micro-ROS in 1 LAN can communicate like ROS2 (DDS middleware)
ROS 2 uses DDS middleware for communication between nodes. If a microcontroller uses micro-ROS, can it communicate in the same way as ROS 2 nodes? Specifically, can MCU1 communicate with MCU2?

